# How to make Next.js "see" the react-dom package?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, next.js, react-dom

This is my first ever Next.js project, and I encountered an odd obstacle. Even though I made sure at least 3 times that I have react-dom and react installed and up-to-date, during `next`, `next build` or `next run` the process aborts with the message:

`The module 'react-dom' was not found. Next.js requires that you include it in the 'dependencies' of your 'package.json'. To add it, run 'npm install --save react-dom'`,

`Error: Cannot find module 'react-dom/server'`,

and:

`Error: > Build failed because of webpack errors`.

Reading on similar problems, I did a couple of things suggested that actually fit my problem, like removing `node_modules` and doing `yarn`, reinstalling `react-dom` and `react`, but none of these helped. Deploying on Now.sh (on which I'm planning to deploy this site) also returns with an error.

This is my `package.json`:

```json
{
  "dependencies": {
    "next": "^9.0.2",
    "react": "^16.8.6",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.6"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start"
  }
}
```

I really made sure the result should be the browser opening my project on `localhost:3000`, but all of the Next.js commands that could make or lead to making this happen abort. Any ideas? Don't hesitate to ask for more code.

Comment: Looks like the library was not installed correctly. Do you see a folder named `react-dom` under `node_modules`? I assumed your file imports other libraries other than `react-dom`. Is this the only library that you got this error?

Comment: did the previous comment help you ? If not, can you show your project folder's structure ?

Comment: @YingZuo I checked into the `node_modules` directory; `react-dom`'s definitely there. @GaëlS [my folder structure](https://imgur.com/a/AZ2rkwY)

Comment: That's very strange. I don't know what can go wrong. I can take a look if you check in your code somewhere.

Comment: @YingZuo initializing a new project fixed this, maybe this was a one-time bug or something.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var ReactDOM = require('react-dom');
```

Then, do

```js
console.log(ReactDOM)
```

to see specifically what sort of errors you will have on the console.